# Vue2: how to get a smooth mouse move?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I am new to using vue for interactive elements, but I have experience in d3. 
I am struggling to get the expected behavior with DOM elements when dragging.

I want to click and move ("drag") and maintain the element's position under the mouse (rather than jumping to upper left corner) and without flickering.

I have read several other posts and could not find an example or answer to what I was looking for.

I have tried a combination of `pageX/Y` `offsetX/Y` `clientX/Y` with to no avail.

Note: in my actual app I am trying on a component via `@<event>.native`, but here, even without that, I can not get it to work

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    x: 100,
    y: 100,
    dragging: false
  },
  methods: {
    startDrag() {
      this.dragging = true;
    },
    stopDrag() {
      this.dragging = false;
    },
    doDrag(event) {
      if (this.dragging) {
        // let style = this.$refs.obj.$el.style

        this.x = event.clientX
        this.y = event.clientY
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    style() {
      return {
        left: `${this.x}px`,
        top: `${this.y}px`,
        position: 'absolute'
      }
    }
  }


});
```

```css
#obj {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id='app'>
  {{dragging}}: {{x}}, {{y}}
  <div ref="obj" id='obj' :style="style" @mousedown="startDrag" @mousemove="doDrag" @mouseup="stopDrag">

  </div>
  {{style}}


</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried applying CSS transitions? Try something like this: `transition: all 2s ease 0s;`

Comment: @SimonHyll thank you for the input. Easing transitions helps, but doesnt fix the upper-left corner problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing - I highly recommend to you not watch on element's movement, but watch on pointer at all page:

```
mounted () {
  document.addEventListener('pointermove', this.doDrag.bind(this))
},
destroyed () {
  document.removeEventListener('pointermove', this.doDrag.bind(this))
}
```

Also, please change coordinates to looks like `{left: this.x - ${HALF_OF_ELEMENTS_SIZE}px}`

Comment: I appreciate the answer but... 1. doesn't work. 2. adding events to the document is exactly what I am looking for in regards to a vue related approach and 3. half of element size is a bit hacky and doesnt solve the core of the question (maintaining the relative mouse position in the element) as you just center it horizontally

Comment: Okey, it was just a several hints to you. Here is full example: [![Edit Vue Template](https://codesandbox.io/static/img/play-codesandbox.svg)](https://codesandbox.io/s/qv313oxj2w)

Comment: Just one thing here - if you bind event listener to element then if you move fast enough - pointerup will be fired.

Comment: Thanks for the codesandbox, but I can not get that thing to move, even at the slowest of speeds... how fast is "fast enough"? Also sometimes I end up dragging the image (e.g. to drop it to the desktop and download the file) instead of the element....

Comment: +1, was able to modifiy it to get it to work (needed `pointer-events: none;` on the `img`), but I would still prefer if you could find a way to do it without using `document.addEventListener`

Comment: Please provide a safari version (pointer events are not supported by safari, so `mousedown`, `mouseup` and whatever `pointercancel` is in safari)

Comment: I think you can just add @mousedown="handleDown" as usual.

Comment: MDN says: The pointercancel event is fired when the browser determines that there are unlikely to be any more pointer events, or if after the pointerdown event is fired, the pointer is then used to manipulate the viewport by panning, zooming, or ....

Comment: Yes, but safari doesnt have `pointer-events`, so `pointer` move / down / up is equivalent to `mouse` move / down / up, but cancel is `mouse-?`

Comment: So, yes. PointerEvent is a more complex.It includes MouseEvent and TouchEvent as well